# While sending mail with javamail on google app engine I get Error: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, post, jakarta-mail

When i use form sending data to servlet which uses function from bean to send email and everything is on GAE i get this massage: "Error: 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL". Please help me, what is wrong here, because i can't find any solution for few days.

Form:

```
<form action="/SendEmailServlet" method="POST">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>To:</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="to" name="to" size="75" value="email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Subject:</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" size="75" value="test">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Message:</b></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="content" name="content" value="test" size="75"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Send"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "/SendEmailServlet", urlPatterns = {"/SendEmailServlet"})
public class SendEmailServlet extends HttpServlet {
@EJB
private EmailSessionBean emailBean;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, MessagingException{      

    String toAddress = request.getParameter("to");
    String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
    String content = request.getParameter("content");


        emailBean.sendEmail(toAddress,subject,content);


        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
          out.println("<html>");
          out.println("<head>");
          out.println("<titleServlet SendEmailServlet</title>");
          out.println("</head>");
          out.println("<body>");
          out.println("<h1> Form Submitted</h1>");
          out.println("</body>");
          out.println("</html>");
        } finally {
          out.close();
        }
}
```

}

Bean is working well I suppose, because when I use it in main function I receive mail.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to override the doPost method in your HttpServlet to be able to accept a POST:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-